# Picking the First string from a List

Tags: string, list, python-2.5

how i can Pick only the First pick in a List in this example?

```
List = [[110, 10, 20 , 30], [120, 40, 50, 60], [130, 70, 80, 90]]
```

The Output should be:

```
Times = [110, 120, 130]
```

Thank you

Comment: Curly braces are used for dictionaries - not lists!

Comment: Assuming it's a list, how about `List[0]` ?

Comment: Your question is improperly formulated. You need to take first elements of embedded lists from list of lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Come on

```
[l[0] for l in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this `new_list = old_list[0]`.

Wouldnt this just Show the Output

```
[110, 10, 20, 30]
```